# Congratulations, Brian M. Scott!

Tags: discussion, specific-user, celebration

Congratulations on reaching 100k reputation! We all appreciate the quality (and quantity) of your posts on Math.SE.

Comment: The decimal representation of numbers is overrated, but Brian certainly isn't :-)

Comment: Congratulations, Brian!

Comment: Congratulations, Brian! Your presence at MSE increases its personal value for me (and lots and lots of others) immensely.

Comment: Way to go, Brian. It's been a near-constant source of amusement to come across questions where I say "Goody, I can answer that. <pause fifteen seconds to think of a response> Oops, Brian beat me to it with a better answer."

Comment: Thank you all. MSE + retirement gives me the best of both worlds: lots of teaching, and no committee and department meetings!

Comment: Congratulations, @BrianM.Scott! I don't like committees and meetings either! But I like learning!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: What can I add to these different deep enthusiasm dedicated to you on this page. Feel how do we think of you in my Hearts. You've been like a luminous candle for us whenever a problem makes frmidable winds to fix the darkness. So I can say just Congratulations Brian! :-)

Comment: Congratulations Brian. I always try to take an example in the way you write your answers: kind and clear explanations. Unfortunately for me the only way to earn reputation is to log-in while you sleep. Your efficiency cannot be beaten.

Comment: Congratulations, Isaac Solomon! You just earned the first `Great Question` badge ever given on Meta.Math.SE. :)

Answer (score 40):

Brian, what more can I say than what others have said already?

I find your manner unassuming, warm and welcoming. You tailor answers to questions so well, showing both sensitivity to those who come here struggling and seeking help, and intellectual acuity when answering questions at a deeper level.

Users like yourself are one of the reasons I stick around!

Thanks!

amy

Answer (score 36):

From his user page:

> I’m a set-theoretic and general topologist with an interest in
>   combinatorics.

I myself am an aspiring combinatorialist with an interest in general topology. For this reason, I see Dr. Scott as a nemesis constantly thwarting my attempt to earn green check marks.

Kidding aside, thank you for your work here at MSE. I've learned a great deal about clarity (not to mention combinatorics and topology) reading your responses.

Comment: Hahaha...I had to burst out laughing, Austin!

Comment: :-) Now I know why I see so many of your answers!

Answer (score 20):

Well deserved. Congratulations, Brian!

Answer (score 20):

I always look forward to reading Brian's comments as well as his answers. Congrats!

Answer (score 17):

Brian, you're the best M.SE user I have ever seen! Your patience towards everybody on this site has been a strong point. I loved the day when you scrolled through my answers and complimented me. The site has been lucky to have such a genius. Good luck for being the first user to reach 200k!

After the [history of MSE post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/history-of-math-stackexchange), should we create one for the history of Brian M. Scott? :-)

Comment: I'm not sure a separate post would be appropriate, but you can add something about Brian (e.g., that he reached 100K mark in November 2012) to the history post. It's a community wiki. If Brian does not like it, he can take it out later.

Comment: @5pm Take the last line as some light-hearted humor: Brian has done so much for this website that he needs a whole post!

Comment: That should say "4th user to reach $\rm 100K".\ $ $\rm 200K$ is far away.

Comment: @MathGems I meant to wish him luck for the future: 200k.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's ambiguous as written (and naturally interpreted as referring to a present achievement).

Answer (score 14):

And the first [gold badge in Combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/254/combinatorics?userid=12042) on Math.SE goes to...

Answer (score 13):

Brian? Sounds familiar... Ahhhh. He answered a bunch of my math questions!

Congratulations, and thank you very much, Brian!

Answer (score 11):

Thank you Brian, you helped me a lot, you answer very fast with great quality, it's unbelievable, you helped me almost all my topology questions.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

Congratulations Brian! You've answered so many of my questions, and you always provide crystal clear explanations. I have no doubt that the 100k reputation is extremely well deserved :).

Answer (score 9):

Congrats Brian, thanks for all the metric spaces help, really appreciate it.